# Loki Helm Chart: Logs Are Only Visible for the Last Hour Despite 2 Days of Installation

Tags: kubernetes, logging, kubernetes-helm, grafana-loki

I have installed loki using this [official helm chart](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/grafana/loki), For some reason it doesn't show logs before 1h I come back after 1h and I only see 1h of logs, it's been installed since 2 days, and this is the behavior since. (see my helm values below)

[image]

```
  ## These are my helm values.
  values:
    monitoring:
      lokiCanary:
        enabled: false
    loki:
      limits_config:
        retention_period: 90d
        compaction_interval: 10m

      tableManager:
        retention_deletes_enabled: true
        retention_period: 90d
      auth_enabled: false
      storage:
        type: s3
        bucketNames:
          chunks: loki-ksa-production-chunks
          ruler: loki-ksa-production-ruler
          admin: loki-ksa-production-admin
        s3:
          endpoint: https://axrocwa5fi5e.compat.objectstorage.me-jeddah-1.oraclecloud.com
          region: me-jeddah-1
          accessKeyId: ${S3_LOKI_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
          secretAccessKey: ${S3_LOKI_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
          insecure: false
          s3ForcePathStyle: true
```

Comment: There's a known issue causing this that I just experienced as well, looks like people are reverting to 2.8.X which corresponds to Helm Chart Version 5.15.0 [GH Ref](https://github.com/grafana/loki/issues/10658)

Comment: Whoops, meant to link this one: [GH Ref](https://github.com/grafana/loki/issues/10529), sorry about that